# Cannot access Swagger in Java Application

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Java 1.7 application, and I have just added Swagger to view the REST api's using [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#adding-the-dependencies-to-your-application) documentation.

I have added the following:

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**MyRestApplication.java**

```
public class MyRestApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> resourceClasses = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

            ...

        resourceClasses.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        resourceClasses.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

        return  resourceClasses;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443/corporateInterface</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The JBoss server starts up as per normal with no errors.

**Question**

How do I access the Swagger ui?

The documentation says:

> You should now be able to access the Swagger definition at
> /swagger.json and /swagger.yaml at the context root of your
> application.

So I have tried the following:

```
https://localhost:8443/corporateInterface/swagger.json
```

and

```
https://localhost:8443/corporateInterface/swagger.yaml
```

But the browser returns a 404 (not found).

I can access my normal application with:

```
https://localhost:8443/corporateInterface/login.do
```

**UPDATE**

I have also tried it with setting the swagger resources in the `Application` class, but still have the same issue of not being able to access swagger.

```
public TravellinckRestApplication() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"https"});
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8443");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/corporateInterface");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}
```